# Can "version" be used as a verb?

Tags: verbs, colloquial-language, verbing

In a software development environment, things have versions, or historic snapshots of how they evolve over time. Can I say "You need to version this or that" so as to refer that something needs historic evolution tracking?

Comment: I've heard this word being used just like you described, but I think it's better to say "You need to add version control" or "You need to add versioning"

Comment: I was planning to use it even as an adjective: versioned item :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your colleague understands it, it is fine. While 'version' is not a verb, English has quite a history of converting nouns to verbs; check this [Calvin and Hobbes comic](http://www.gocomics.com/calvinandhobbes/1993/01/25).

Comment: "Version" absolutely is a verb in the realm of software development, so I wouldn't say "'version' is not a verb". It does fall into the relam of jargon, however.

Answer (score 3):

Well, you *can* do it, and in the particular environment that you've described it would probably be a perfectly intelligible (and useful) use of the word.

Outside of that context, not so much.

Answer (score 3):

English (and most languages) tends to develop jargon significantly. According to [Webster's dictionary](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/jargon), jargon means:

> the technical terminology or characteristic idiom of a special activity or group

That said, as a native English speaker and software developer, within the software development community, I think you would be casting yourself as an outsider by specifically trying to avoid this language. Version is definitely used as a verb and an adjective in the software development world.

Comment: So, go ahead with "You need to version this" and "This thing is versioned"?

Comment: For sure. I hear that sort of thing all the time, in software development.